# Angular - Clear stored routes with condition on route (RouteReuseStrategy)

Tags: angular, router

I'm using RouteReuseStrategy to store routes with some conditions. I want to access a form from another form, without losing the filled inputs in the first form, for the functional context.

I have two questions :

1) Currently, I set a property in the ActivatedRoute data property. I don't think it's a good thing because there's no available setter for the data property. How can I do that properly, without condition on the URL ?

2) If I click on a menu item of my application, I want to reset all the stored routes wwith the RouteReuseStrategy. How can I give that condition into the route ?

My current code :

```
    import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from '../auth/auth.component';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  /**
   * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later.
   * Fired when shouldReuseRoute returns false
   * If it returns true, the method store will be fired.
   * @param route current route
   */
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const url: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(route);
    if (route.data['shouldReuseRoute']) {
      return true;
    } else {
      delete this.handlers[url];
      return false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Determines the action we want to do when storing a route.
   * Fired when shouldDeatch returns true.
   * @param route : current route
   * @param handle : identifies the stored component
   */
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    const url: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(route);
    this.handlers[url] = handle;
  }

  /**
   * Determines if the current route should be reused from the stored components or not.
   * Fired when shouldReuseRoute returns false
   * @param route current route
   */
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // Reset all the stored routes if we're on the AuthComponent
    if (route.component === AuthComponent) {
      this.handlers = {};
      return false;
    }
    const url: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(route);
    return !!this.handlers[url];
  }

  /**
   * Returns the stored route we want to reuse..
   * Fired when shouldAttach returns true
   * @param route current route
   */
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    const url: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(route);
    if (!route.routeConfig || !this.handlers[url]) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return this.handlers[url];
    }
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const currentUrl: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(curr);
    const futureUrl: string = this.getRouteIdentifier(future);
    return currentUrl === futureUrl;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the unique identifier for each route
   * @param route: route to identify
   */
  getRouteIdentifier(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
    return route.url.join('/');
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I miss understood the question.

To store the data you can do this in the routing.module.ts by adding a data property.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    data: { shouldReuseRoute: true }
  }
];
```

Then you just set true or false for every route, here deciding which paths to store or not to store.

By storing it you will re-use the route and by not it will then recreate the component everytime.

**EDIT:** You can access this data within the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) under the data property.

```
store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle) {
  let data = route.data.shouldReuseRoute; // here is the data attribute

  // referenced in the comments, to get a property dynamically from the component itself
  let componentVar = handle['componentRef']['instance']['shouldReuseRoute'] // must be created in the component view
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But, as I was saying, I need to activate the route storage on very particular conditions. I can't set this parameter in the route file

Comment: You could also achieve this by adding a parameter to the route then read for the parameter in the route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot?

Comment: Have you got an example of this ? Because I don't know how to set a parameter on a route and make it persistent to be used on differente files

Comment: @Helayxa have you found the answer to this? I am needing to perform the same type action. I need to store the route cache BUT clear it when a condition is true.

Comment: @billy_comic To do this dynamically you can just prototype it on the route or 
 from inside whichever component that is needed, you can create a variable which you switch. And then accessing it through the stored handler itself, which can be found here: handler['componentRef']['instance']['shouldReuseRoute'].

Comment: I will give this a try.

Comment: how it is made working as conditional, I am also trying to find solution but with no success